# Only one game object moves in unity when I have 3 identical objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, rigid-bodies

This has been annoying me for a while and I can't find a solution. Only `ground3` moves while the other 2 stay in place. Im using unity and doing a 2d project.

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GroundMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float globalspeed;

    public GameObject Ground1;
    public float Ground1Speed;
    Rigidbody2D rb1;

    public GameObject Ground2;
    public float Ground2Speed;
    Rigidbody2D rb2;

    public GameObject Ground3;
    public float Ground3Speed;
    Rigidbody2D rb3;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb1 = Ground1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb2 = Ground1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb3 = Ground1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        rb1.velocity = new Vector2(globalspeed + Ground1Speed, 0);
        rb2.velocity = new Vector2(globalspeed + Ground2Speed, 0);
        rb3.velocity = new Vector2(globalspeed + Ground3Speed, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure everything is assigned in your inspector and that all your objects have a rigid body component?

Comment: Yeah 100% I checked like 10 times

Comment: Why does `rb3 = Ground1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` and not `rb3 = Ground3.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`?

Comment: Because I'm stupid and that's the solution

Comment: You got the rb from ground1 every time so only 1 was got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `Start()` Method, when you assigned the rigidbodies, you assigned all of them to the rigidbody in the `Ground1` GameObject, the method should be like this:

```
void Start()
{
    rb1 = Ground1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb2 = Ground2.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    rb3 = Ground3.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
```

Comment: plus I suggest you use C# naming conventions (Camel casing for variables) for example: `ground1` `ground1Speed` `globalSpeed`